# That vs Which in plural contexts

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Almost all **animals that hibernate** prepare to do so by eating large amounts
>   of food,which they convert to fat.
>
> Among birds **that forage in** tree trunks, nuthatches are the only ones
>   that regularly feed with their heads facing downward.

Why is the usage of 'that' in the following sentences correct. These involve plural sentences and shouldn't 'which' be used instead.

Also if there is any rule which differentiates the usage of 'that' for humans and animals, please do post that too.

PS : I've generally seen that used in singular sentences while those used in plural. Any examples involving the contrary would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do not confuse *that/those* the demonstrative pronoun/determiner with *that* the relative pronoun (which is more commonly used in the place of *which*, especially in less formal English).

Answer (score 3):

*That* is perfectly OK here. Grammatical number does not enter into the choice between *that* and *which*. Both of them (indeed, *all* English relative pronouns) may be used in both singular and plural contexts.

The only distinction between *that* and *which/who/whom* is that *that* is not permitted in non-restrictive bound relative clauses or as the object of prepositions:

> John, <s>that</s> **who** had prepared better than the rest of us, came in first.
>   Put it back in the box from <s>that</s> **which** you took it.

*That* is rarely found at the head of fused relative clauses today; it is usually replaced by *what*. , When it is used there it should be understood as a demonstrative rather than a relative, and what follows it is a reduced relative clause with the relativizer deleted.

> Your pain is trivial compared to that she suffered = *that which she suffered*

Some of the prissier stylists demand that only *that* be employed in restrictive relative clauses, but this has no justification in contemporary or historical practice.